# Recovering from soft out-of-memory errors in OCaml

Tags: garbage-collection, out-of-memory, ocaml

I'm writing a ISO-comforming Prolog system in OCaml. In order to conform to ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995, an implementation has to handle out-of-memory situations properly:

> ## 7 Language concepts and semantics
>
> ### 7.12 Errors
>
> #### 7.12.2 Error classification
>
> h) There shall be a Resource Error at any stage of execution when the processor has insufficient resources to complete execution. It has the form `resource_error(Imp_dep_atom)` where `Imp_dep_atom` denotes an implementation dependent term.

So a ISO-conforming Prolog system must provide the following three features:

1. `resource_error(memory)` is thrown upon running out of heap space.
2. `resource_error(stack)` is thrown upon running out of call stack.
3. Both exceptions can be caught within Prolog using the built-in `catch/3`.

So far, so good! With the help of ["Today's trick : memory limits with Gc alarms" [discuss.ocaml.org]](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/todays-trick-memory-limits-with-gc-alarms/4431) I was able to enforce a *soft* (application level) memory limit.

When I run a particular query (which requires ~60% of the memory specified as the soft limit) several times in a row, however,
something funny is going on:
I get an answer every other time and run out of memory every other time.

This behavior is okay as far as ISO-conformance goes, but I'd rather get an answer every time than get it every other time. Duh!

This should be doable, especially if the limit I hit is *soft* (self-imposed on the OCaml level).

So: how can I force the OCaml GC to do (even) more work than with `Gc.compact`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for something like:

```
Gc.set {Gc.get () with Gc.space_overhead = 40}
```

`Gc.compact` is a one-shot solution: the GC does some work when you call it in order to free up space. And you can't make the GC do more one-shot work than with `Gc.compact` in order to free up more memory. After `Gc.compact ()`, only live data exists in memory chunks that have been reserved by OCaml for the heap, if what has been reserved is too much above what is actually needed, the unnecessary chunks have been freed, etc.

What you want is probably the GC to permanently spend more time in order to use less memory. You can obtain that behavior by setting the `space_overhead` parameter, possibly `max_overhead`. See the [relevant chapter of the OCaml documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Gc.html) for details:

> type control = {
> …
> mutable space_overhead : int;   (*
> The major GC speed is computed from this parameter. This is the memory that will be "wasted" because the GC does not immediately
> collect unreachable blocks. It is expressed as a percentage of the
> memory used for live data. The GC will work more (use more CPU time
> and collect blocks more eagerly) if space_overhead is smaller.
> Default: 80.

Other GC parameters documented in the same chapter may also influence memory consumption indirectly. It all depends on what you are willing to trade in exchange for less memory use.

Comment: Maybe I should set `space_overhead = 40` once the major heap size has crossed a certain size (say, 50% of the soft limit)?

Comment: @repeat This is what I do, but you need to poll at the appropriate interval to detect that memory use has passed the limit that you settled on.

Comment: Isn't the GC alarm handler (see "Today's trick") the right place?

Comment: @repeat I believe that you refer to https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/todays-trick-memory-limits-with-gc-alarms/4431 . The advice there is not very good. First, according to the documentation, “Gc.create_alarm f will arrange for f to be called at the end of each major GC cycle”, so this is still a kind of polling. Second, it's not necessarily very good polling. If the program spends a long time allocating lots of short-lived data with a small heap, the function will be called unnecessarily often.

Comment: @repeat Worse, heap expansion does not take place at the end of GC cycles, so the heap size can expand a lot, several times, before a cycle finishes and the function is called. With knowledge of what your program is doing, you should easily find a better spot to check periodically how much memory is currently used. There is simply to the best of my knowledge no way to install an alarm for the OCaml runtime to tell you that it just increased the quantity of memory used.